# Show symbol name in dataframe plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a `dataframe` that contains several `columns`, `[date],[symbol],[close],['ave'], ['upper'], ['lower']`.

I set the index

```
df = df.set_index('date')
```

looks like this:

```
           symbol   close      ave    upper    lower
date                                                
2019-01-02    MMM  190.95  194.030  208.758  179.303
2019-01-03    MMM  183.76  192.780  206.450  179.111
2019-01-04    MMM  191.32  192.236  205.174  179.299
2019-01-07    MMM  190.88  191.646  203.619  179.674
...
```

When I plot it,

```
df.plot()
```

everything looks great including the `legend` shows the color key for each line in the `plot`, except I don't see symbol in the `legend`. I have tried:

```
df.plot(label=symbol)
```

but nothing shows up?

Comment: Can you show an example of your dataframe? df.head()

Comment: See original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because symbol is not float type.

Only the column labels that have been represented are shown in the legend.

Then you can do something like this:

```
new_df=df.set_index(['date','symbol']).unstack()
print(new_df)

             close      ave    upper    lower
symbol         MMM      MMM      MMM      MMM
date                                         
2019-01-02  190.95  194.030  208.758  179.303
2019-01-03  183.76  192.780  206.450  179.111
2019-01-04  191.32  192.236  205.174  179.299
2019-01-07  190.88  191.646  203.619  179.674
```

---

```
new_df.plot()
```

[image]